# Find a specific element and its value with XPath in XML PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm totally new to **XPath** so take it easy with me ;-)

I'm trying to grab content from a node

The XML structure looks like (simplified OOXML):

```
 <w:p>
     <w:r>
         <w:drawing>
             <wp:anchor wp14:editId="3BCCBF8F" wp14:anchorId="1109B0B5" 
             distR="114300" distL="114300" distB="0" distT="0" 
             allowOverlap="1" layoutInCell="1" locked="0" behindDoc="0" 
             relativeHeight="251663360" simplePos="0">
                 <a:graphic a="{url}">
                     <a:graphicData uri="{urli}">
                         <pic:pic xmlns:pic="{uri}">
                             <pic:blipFill>
                                 <a:blip cstate="print" r:embed="rId13"/>
{all closing tag p, r, w etc}

 <w:p>
     <w:r>
         <w:drawing>
             <wp:anchor wp14:editId="3BCCBF8F" wp14:anchorId="1109B0B5" 
             distR="114300" distL="114300" distB="0" distT="0" 
             allowOverlap="1" layoutInCell="1" locked="0" behindDoc="0" 
             relativeHeight="251663360" simplePos="0">
                 <a:graphic a="{url}">
                     <a:graphicData uri="{urli}">
                         <pic:pic xmlns:pic="{uri}">
                             <pic:blipFill>
                                 <a:blip cstate="print" r:embed="rId14"/>
{all closing tag p, r, w etc}
```

My code looks like this:

`$result` below is simply a string with the xml

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($result);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$xpath->registerNamespace(
   'word', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
                    );

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//word:drawing//word:anchor') as $index => $node) {
    var_dump($node);
}
```

I get an empty node. I'm obviously doing something wrong. I'm expecting the node of anchor with this code.

I could basically loop threw each node and find childitems for each node, *but that seems to be wasted XPath*...

***Something like:***

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//word:drawing') as $index => $node) {
    foreach($xpath->evaluate('*', $node) as $anchornode) {
        var_dump($anchornode);
    } 
}
```

**What I really want to do is fetching the** r:embed values in the drawing-element ( rId13 and rId14 )

I've been trying to find what I want in other questions here on SO (there are a lot).... If you find one, just refer me to that question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp:anchor` is in a different namespace (from `w:document`). Look for the `xmlns:wp` attribute. This is the namespace definition for the `wp` prefix.

You have to register an alias/prefix for that namespace as well.

```
$xpath->registerNamespace(
   'word', 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
);    
$xpath->registerNamespace(
   'wp', 'urn:???'
);
```

Your code registers the prefix `word` for the namespace URI `http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main`

This allows to Xpath processor to resolve the prefix in the Xpath expression. You could read it as:

`//word:drawing` -> `//{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}drawing`

The XML parser does the same with the node names.

`<w:drawing/>` -> `<{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}drawing/>`

That is how it matches up. But because something like that would be really difficult to read (for humans) and result in large XML files aliases/prefixes are used. You could use the same prefixes as in the document (`w`, `wp`, ...) in the Xpath expressions, but you will have to register them to the same namespace URIs. Think of the prefixes as variable names, keep them readable so that you can understand your code later.

Comment: Aha thanx a lot! That really put me in right direction!